# IndexError: list index out of range due to empty list within list

Tags: python, list, filter, empty-list

I have a list of a *group* of lists inside and I'm trying to create a dictionary by assigning each element in a group as a value to a key. However, one of these groups is just an empty list. I tried to use the filter() function to eliminate that empty list and I also tried using the remove() function, however, none of those work. It results in the following error:

```
my_dict = {'letter': g[0], 'my_arr': g[1], 'second_letter_conf': g[2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [['A', np.array([4, 2, 1, 6]), [['B', 5]]], [' '], ['C', np.array([8, 5, 5, 9]), [['D', 3]]]]
# my_list = list(filter(None, my_list)) # does not work

for g in my_list:
    # if g == [' ']:
    #     my_list.remove(g) # does not work
    my_dict = {'letter': g[0], 'my_arr': g[1], 'second_letter_conf': g[2]}
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I eliminate that one empty list from `my_list`?

Comment: Hi, you can filter the elements with listcomprehension like this : **[i for i in my_list if i]**

Comment: If you like to use the filter function you can try: **filter(lambda x: x, my_list)**

Comment: @baskettaz: One, if it was a truly empty list you were filtering out, you'd just use `filter(None, my_list)` (or equivalently, `filter(bool, my_list)`, which is special-cased to operate the same way). Two, in this case it's not an empty `list`, so that `filter` and that listcomp won't work (`[' ']` is truthy, it would pass the test). Three, if you need a `lambda` to use `filter`, just use a listcomp or genexpr with the equivalent code inlined; it's cleaner looking and faster (and only *very* slightly more verbose, depending on the name of your loop variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mutate a `list` as you iterate it safely. But you can just skip the element and move to the next; you were quite close really:

```
for g in my_list:
    if g == [' ']:  # I might suggest instead doing if len(g) != 3:
                    # if any length 3thing is good, and other lengths should be discarded
        continue  # Skip this element, go to next
    my_dict = {'letter': g[0], 'my_arr': g[1], 'second_letter_conf': g[2]}
```

If you need to exclude it from `my_list` (you'll be using it over and over and don't want to have it there in the future), a quick pre-filter with a listcomp is the simplest solution (and if it lets you assume length three data for what remains, it will allow you to unpack for cleaner/more-self-documenting code in subsequent use):

```
my_list = [x for x in my_list if x != [' ']]
for let, arr, let2_conf in my_list:
    my_dict = {'letter': let, 'my_arr': arr, 'second_letter_conf': let2_conf}
```